Customize Image Property in Sitecore Rich Text Field
I want to add some options in the CSS Class DD in image property of Sitecore rich text field. And want to add Src field to the panel as in the image which to be shown below the image and Tile above the image.
Is it possible ? Can someone please help to achieve this?


In order to customize the image properties dialog on the rich text editor, you need to place the SetImageProperties.ascx file inside the sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Dialogs.
This is location where all the dialogs that are customized are placed. This is set from the following setting inside Telerik RadEditor.
ExternalDialogsPath="~/sitecore/shell/controls/rich text editor/Dialogs/"

Thereafter additional element can be added inside the ascx file as below.
<div class="redRow">
    <label class="redLabel" for="ImageCustom">
        Image Custom
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="ImageCustom" name="ImageCustom" />
</div>

Thereafter need to modify javascript functions inside the ascx file to read and set custom variable.

Firstly modify _setupChildren function as below to initialize the instance variable.

this._imageCustom=$get("ImageCustom");


Thereafter, modify the loadImageProperties function as below to load the custom property when dialog is opened.

this._imageCustom.value=this._getAttribute(currentImage,"imagecustom");


Then finally modify the getModifiedImage function to set the custom attribute value in the image.

this._setAttribute(resultImage,"imagecustom",this._imageCustom.value);

Using above way, you can add the custom property on the properties dialog for the image in the rich text editor.
Note: Original SetImageProperties.ascx file can be downloaded from the Telerik.Web.UI dll inside your Sitecore bin folder.
More details on setting and reading these additonal values can be found here:
https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-imageproperties-dialog-with-additional-fields-for-images
Update:
In order to add custom classes for the css dropdown, you will need to edit the sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Toolsfile.xml to add the class inside <classes> section of the file.
Therefore add the css for the custom class, inside css file declared inside WebStylesheet setting. By default, it is specified as default.css. Make sure to sure clear browser cache after making this changes as this file is cached.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any doubts.

Thank you @ckhana. Let me check this.

@RashmiRanjan Added updates for the javscript changes to be carried out to read and set the custom variable. Let me know in case you face any issues.

Trying to add class in the DD, but its not working. Tried this. But I cant see this class anywhere in the image property model.
test-left

And in which location i ll find WebStylesheet ?

@RashmiRanjan Did you added the css for this class "test-left" inside WebStylesheet settings file. By default it is located inside default.css file inside webroot. Check the showconfig.aspx page..There you will get the WebStylesheet setting..Let me know in case you have any doubts...

Also make sure your clear your browser cache after you make changes on Default.css file...since this file is cached...

@RashmiRanjan is the issue solved?

This works. Thank you @ckhanna

Glad to hear that @RashmiRanjan!!!
